# "deprecated" in ip addr sh?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, ipv6

When I run `ip addr sh` I see my secondary IPv6 addresses have `deprecated` next to them, whilst my primary IPv6 does not. Could someone help explain this ?

```
inet6 2001:DB8::aaaa/64 scope global deprecated 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft 0sec
inet6 2001:DB8::bbbb/64 scope global 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:DB8::cccc/64 scope global deprecated
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this :

```
allow-hotplug ens18
iface ens18 inet6 static
        address 2001:DB8::bbbb/64
        gateway 2001:DB8::ffff/64
        dns-nameservers 2001:DB8::1 2001:DB8::2

auto ens18:0
iface ens18:0 inet6 static
        name Sec1
        address 2001:DB8::aaaa/64

auto ens18:1
iface ens18:1 inet6 static
        name Sec2
        address 2001:DB8::cccc/64
```

Comment: [IPv6 Source Address Selection on Linux](http://www.davidc.net/networking/ipv6-source-address-selection-linux). (Basically, "deprecated" means "don't use this as a source address if at all possible".)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*deprecated address* is an IPv6 concept described for example in
[RFC4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862):

> deprecated address - An address assigned to an interface whose use is
> discouraged, but not forbidden.  A deprecated address should no longer
> be used as a source address in new communications, but packets sent
> from or to deprecated addresses are delivered as expected.  A
> deprecated address may continue to be used as a source address in
> communications where switching to a preferred address causes hardship
> to a specific upper-layer activity (e.g., an existing TCP connection).

You can find that "deprecated" is printed by `ip` if IFA_F_DEPRECATED
flag is set on an interface
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/ip/ipaddress.c#n1195

I don't know which part of Debian init system sets IPv6 address to
deprecated but you can try to create a new IPv6 address and mark it as
deprecated using `preferred_lft 0` flag with `ip`:

```
$ sudo ip  -6 addr add 2000:0db8:0:f101::1/64 dev eth0  preferred_lft 0
$ ip addr show | grep deprecated
    inet6 2000:db8:0:f101::1/64 scope global deprecated
```